# How to force windows to show the error message?

Tags: windows

Sometimes, apparently on Windows XP, when something goes wrong with my app, Windows tries to help showing a "Send error report" dialog.

But to find out the real error it would be better for me to see the actual error message. Is there any configuration or log that I can look at to see what´s the error?

Comment: This happens because your app raises an exception that is not handled. It's best to catch this in your application. Without knowing any details of how your app is implemented, it's impossible to tell you how to do that.

Comment: There are lots of places that could be raising the exception. I need the message to find that place and catch the exception.

Comment: Indeed you do. But my comment still stands. You want a top level exception handler. I can't tell you how to implement it because I know nothing about your app.

Comment: But, in some versions (or configuration sets) of windows it shows the actual message, and not the report error dialog.

Comment: It depends on how Windows Error Reporting is configured on that machine. I don't understand why you want your program to die with unhandled exceptions. Your meant to want that not to happen!

Comment: I think I´m not being clear here. I neeed that message to find the place where the problem is and handle it. Unfortunately I´m not able to have a top level exception handler.

Comment: If you can't change your program then you'll need to change the global configuration of the target machine. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old copy of `NTSD` is installed by default with Windows XP. You can set the following registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
```

to call `ntsd`. It will catch all unhandled exceptions. IIRC, it is where DrWatson use to live.

Here is a [detailled how-to](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX105888) that will save the dump to a file. I prefer that method, but  you can also have the debugger start an interactive session.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2284138/591064) is similar.