# How to find out if a program crashed with subprocess?

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess, popen

My application creates subprocesses. Usually, these processeses run and terminate without any problems. However, sometimes, they crash.

I am currently using the python [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to create these subprocesses. I check if a subprocess crashed by invoking the `Popen.poll()` method. Unfortunately, since my debugger is activated at the time of a crash, polling doesn't return the expected output.

I'd like to be able to see the debugging window(not terminate it) and still be able to detect if a process is crashed in the python code.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem. I used the solution given in another question [Can the "Application Error" dialog box be disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735170/can-the-application-error-dialog-box-be-disabled)

Comment: similar code in python - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069224/handling-subprocess-crash-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

When your debugger opens, the process isn't finished yet - and `subprocess` only knows if a process is running or finished. So no, there is not a way to do this via `subprocess`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there another way to solve this problem with python?

Comment: If your subprocesses have some means of output that your master process could monitor, they could output "I'm alive" indicators at regular intervals, and the absence of such an indicator for a significantly long period of time could be taken to mean that the subprocess has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Items of consideration:

subprocess.check_output() for your child processes return codes
psutil for process & child analysis (and much more)
threading library, to monitor these child states in your script as well once you've decided how you want to handle the crashing, if desired

```
import psutil
myprocess = psutil.Process(process_id) # you can find your process id in various ways of your choosing
for child in myprocess.children():
    print("Status of child process is: {0}".format(child.status()))
```

You can also use the threading library to load your subprocess into a separate thread, and then perform the above psutil analyses concurrently with your other process.

If you find more, let me know, it's no coincidence I've found this post.