# Handling subprocess crash in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a python script from windows command prompt. It calls the function below, which converts an MP3 file to a wave file using [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

```
def convert_mp3_to_wav(input_filename, output_filename):
    """
    converts the incoming mp3 file to wave file
    """
    if not os.path.exists(input_filename):
        raise AudioProcessingException, "file %s does not exist" % input_filename

    command = ["lame", "--silent", "--decode", input_filename, output_filename]

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0 or not os.path.exists(output_filename):
        raise AudioProcessingException, stdout

    return output_filename
```

Unfortunately LAME always crashes (and lives up to its name) on a certain MP3s. The Windows "Your program has crashed" dialog appears, which freezes my script. Once I close the windows dialog, the AudioProcessingException is raised.
Instead of having to tell Windows to shut up, I'd just like the script to raise the exception and then move onto the next MP3.

Is there any way around this? Preferably by altering the script rather than running it with Unix.

I am using Windows 7, and Python 2.6

Comment: +1 for "Preferably by altering the script rather than running it with Unix."

Comment: Have you tried disabling error reporting in Windows?

Comment: Erm no, I haven't... I shall investigate!

Comment: I turned off Windows Error Reporting, but I still get a notification that halts the script running. I'm not sure turning off more parts of Windows would make my sysadmin happy either!

Comment: This is tricky, I can't find any info on fixing this myself. For interest, have you tried using .wait() instead of .communicate()? I realize that would lock your code until encoding finishes though, or may not solve anything. Just a test.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After some more googling, I stumbled upon this
http://www.activestate.com/blog/2007/11/supressing-windows-error-report-messagebox-subprocess-and-ctypes

It required a bit of tinkering, but the method below now doesn't get annoying Windows messages :)
Note the creationflags=subprocess_flags in the subprocess.Popen too

```
def convert_mp3_to_wav(input_filename, output_filename):

    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        # Don't display the Windows GPF dialog if the invoked program dies.
        # See comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
        # How to suppress crash notification dialog?, Jan 14,2004 -
        # Raymond Chen's response [1]

        import ctypes
        SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX = 0x0002 # From MSDN
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
        subprocess_flags = 0x8000000 #win32con.CREATE_NO_WINDOW?
    else:
        subprocess_flags = 0



    """
    converts the incoming mp3 file to wave file
    """
    if not os.path.exists(input_filename):
        raise AudioProcessingException, "file %s does not exist" % input_filename

    #exec("lame {$tmpname}_o.mp3 -f {$tmpname}.mp3 && lame --decode {$tmpname}.mp3 {$tmpname}.wav");
    command = ["lame", "--silent", "--decode", input_filename, output_filename]

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess_flags)
    (stdout, stderr) = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0 or not os.path.exists(output_filename):
        raise AudioProcessingException, stdout

    return output_filename
```

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this answer 3 years later, but I need to disable Windows error reporting for a Python script I'm trying to execute, but I'm not using subprocesses, but Threads. I added your first "paragraph" of code and now the error doesn't appear, but no information about the crash is being shown in the command line. Is this normal?

Comment: @Shadark I don't remember doing anything with those errors, so I doubt I cared about the lack of information at the time. As you say, it has been 3 years... and I now don't own a Windows machine, so I can't really help! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. Even if the application crashes the correct application output will be returned.