# How to launch crashing (rarely) application in subprocess

Tags: windows, python-3.x, crash, subprocess

I'm having python application which needs to execute proprietary application (which crashes from time to time) about 20 000 times a day.

The problem is when application crashes, Windows automatically triggers [WerFault](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/WerFault_AeDebug.png) which will keep program hanging, thus [python's `subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will wait forever for user input (that application has to run on weekends, on holidays, 24/7... so this is not acceptable).

If though about using `sleep; poll; kill; terminate` but that would mean losing ability to use `communicate()`, application can run from few miliseconds to 2 hours, so setting fixed timeout will be ineffective

I also tried [turning on automatic debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (use a script which would take a crash dump of an application and terminate id), but somehow this *howto* doesn't work on my server (WerFault still appears and waits for user input).

Several other tutorials like [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/265458-werfault-exe-how-disable.html) didn't take any effect either.

**Question**:
is there a way how to prevent WerFault from displaying (waiting for user input)? <sub>this is more system then programming question</sub>

**Alternative question**: is there a *graceful* way in python how to detect application crash (whether *WerFault* was displayed)

Comment: You could add the crashing application to wer exclusion list and then depend on local dumps for crash dump. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069224/handling-subprocess-crash-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple (and ugly) answer, monitor for `WerFault.exe` instances from time to time, specially the one associated with the `PID` of the offending application. And kill it. Dealing with `WerFault.exe` is complicated but you don't want to disable it -- see [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx) service.

1. Get a list of processes by name that match `WerFault.exe`. I use [`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) package. Be careful with `psutil` because processes are cached, use `psutil.get_pid_list()`.
2. Decode its command line by using `argparse`. This might be overkill but it leverages existing python libraries.
3. Identify the process that is holding your application according to its `PID`.

This is a simple implementation.

```
def kill_proc_kidnapper(self, child_pid, kidnapper_name='WerFault.exe'):
    """
    Look among all instances of 'WerFault.exe' process for an specific one
    that took control of another faulting process.
    When 'WerFault.exe' is launched it is specified the PID using -p argument:

    'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WerFault.exe -u -p 5012 -s 68'
                             |               |
                             +-> kidnapper   +-> child_pid

    Function uses `argparse` to properly decode process command line and get
    PID. If PID matches `child_pid` then we have found the correct parent
    process and can kill it.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-u', action='store_false', help='User name')
    parser.add_argument('-p', type=int, help='Process ID')
    parser.add_argument('-s', help='??')

    kidnapper_p = None
    child_p = None

    for proc in psutil.get_pid_list():
        if kidnapper_name in proc.name:
            args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args(proc.cmdline)
            print proc.name, proc.cmdline

            if args.p == child_pid:
                # We found the kidnapper, aim.
                print 'kidnapper found: {0}'.format(proc.pid)
                kidnapper_p = proc

    if psutil.pid_exists(child_pid):
        child_p = psutil.Process(child_pid)

    if kidnapper_p and child_pid:
        print 'Killing "{0}" ({1}) that kidnapped "{2}" ({3})'.format(
            kidnapper_p.name, kidnapper_p.pid, child_p.name, child_p.pid)
        self.taskkill(kidnapper_p.pid)
        return 1
    else:
        if not kidnapper_p:
            print 'Kidnapper process "{0}" not found'.format(kidnapper_name)
        if not child_p:
            print 'Child process "({0})" not found'.format(child_pid)

    return 0
```

Now, `taskkill` function invokes `taskkill` commmand with correct `PID`.

```
def taskkill(self, pid):
    """
    Kill task and entire process tree for this process
    """
    print('Task kill for PID {0}'.format(pid))
    cmd = 'taskkill /f /t /pid {0}'.format(pid)
    subprocess.call(cmd.split())
```

Comment: Very nice first answer :) I'm basically doing something like this already, but instead of killing process I notify admins via nagios so they can create crash dump or so.

Answer (score -2):

I see no reason as to why your program needs to crash, find the offending piece of code, and put it into a try-statement.

http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: The problem is with proprietary application which is crashing. We cannot do anything about it (poor support) :(

Comment: Applications crash. That's a fact of life. Even if it is your application and you can fix the crash, it often makes sense to handle crashes. In this case it's 3rd party application that can't be fixed anyway.