# How to get frozen process id from werfault process

Tags: c#, process

I'm wondering is this possible to get related process id from werfault process in C#. I don't want to disable werfault service, only get a related (frozen) process id. I wrote this code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    if (p.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("werfault"))
    {
        //getting related process id?
    }
}
```

For example: werfault service reporting that 'programX has stopped working'. I'm using the code above to find werfault process and then kill it and retrieving programX pid (which I can't do right now).

I found partial answer here: [How to launch crashing (rarely) application in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948611/how-to-launch-crashing-rarely-application-in-subprocess) but this works for python.

Is this possible to retrieve? Do I need any external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Process[] psWerFaultReporter = Process.GetProcessesByName("WerFault");
  int werfaultProcessId = -1;
  if (psWerFaultReporter.Length > 0)
  {
        werfaultProcessId = psWerFaultReporter[0].Id;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        if (p.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("werfault"))
        {
            // Get the CommandLine string from the werfault.exe
            string startupParam = GetCommandLine(p);

            // Get the ProcessID of the frozen Process.
            // Sure you can optimize this part, but it works in this case :)
            int pID = int.Parse(startupParam.Split(new string[] { "-p" }, StringSplitOptions.None).
                      Last().Split(new string[] { "-s" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First().Trim());

            // Get the frozen Process.
            Process frozenProcess = Process.GetProcessById(pID);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the CommandLine from a Process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string GetCommandLine(Process pProcess)
    {
        // Create a new CommandLine with the FileName of the given Process.
        var commandLine = new StringBuilder(pProcess.MainModule.FileName);
        commandLine.Append(" ");

        // Now we need to query the CommandLine of the process with ManagementObjectSearcher.
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + pProcess.Id))
        {
            // Append the arguments to the CommandLine.
            foreach (var @object in searcher.Get())
            {
                commandLine.Append(@object["CommandLine"]);
                commandLine.Append(" ");
            }
        }

        // Return the CommandLine.
        return commandLine.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Whenever a process raises an exception, windows starts the werfault.exe, which is found under "C:\Windows\System 32\WerFault.exe. Windows automatically passes the pid of the frozen or crashed application to that WerFault.exe, which can be retrieved by using the "GetCommandLine" Function. So if you want to get the frozen application related to a WerFault Process, you will first have to get the CommandLine, that has been passed to that WerFault.exe. This command Line contains the process ID of the frozen/crashed process.

Comment: The Command Line looks something like : 
"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WerFault.exe -u -p 5012 -s 68"

So in this case 5012 would be the process ID of the frozen Process. With this ID you can just search for that specific Process by using the Process.GetProcessByID Function