# Failed to get frozen process name from WerFault.exe

Tags: c#, process

I want to restart frozen process automatically, and I tried the methods provided in the related question [How to get frozen process ID from WerFault process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26033896/9547388).

```
Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("WerFault");
if (pro.Tolist().Count > 0)
    {
        string CrashName = pro[0].MainWindowTitle;
    }
```

However, I failed to get the name from WerFault. The CrashName, or MainWindowTitle, is empty, and the MainWindowHandle is 0.

Did I ignore any important step?

Comment: if the process is frozen I wouldnt expect to get any properties from it. It wont be responding

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain the issue clearly. WerFault is not the frozen process but error report process, which ought to provide user and MS some information related to the frozen process.

Comment: but I wouldnt expect anything to be giving you the title etc because the process froze, it cant return those details