# Suppressing Python Subprocess crash in Windows

Tags: python, crash, subprocess

The question I have is virtually identical to the one posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069224/handling-subprocess-crash-in-windows). However the solution provided there is not working.

Description of my problem: I'm running seven (7) multiple processes concurrently to crank through hundreds of simulations. Once in a while, Python will crash and a Windows message box is forced to the screen. This makes the subprocess un-killable until I manually click 'Ok' on the message box. The other subprocesses continue to launch and terminate normally.

The relevant part of my 'dispatcher' script looks like this:

```
import os

# this is the accepted answer from the older SO question
import ctypes
SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX = 0x0002
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)
subprocess_flags = 0x8000000

# some variables
worker_script = 'C:\Example\worker.py'
exe = 'C:\\Anaconda\\python.exe'
new_env = os.environ
new_env['PATH'] = exe + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

# this section is actually in a loop, launching the worker script with      
# different combinations of param1 and param2
cmd = [exe, worker_script, param1, param2]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=new_env, creationflags=subprocess_flags)
if proc.poll() is not None:
    proc.kill()
```

I'm on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, using Python 2.7.9. I suspect that the previously referenced solution needs to be updated, but I've been unable to find the solution myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several useful bits for `SetErrorMode` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It would be interesting to try `0x8007`.

Comment: I'm in the process of testing the error flag `0x8007` suggested by @tdelaney. This will take some time, because the crashes seem to occur randomly, but I will provide an update as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @Vinay87 No, I've never resolved this issue.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for responding :) Neither did I.