# Disabling Debug/Close when on StackOverflow exception

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, stack-overflow

I've been trying to avoid the Debug/Close dialog when I get a stack overflow exception in my application (I need my application to shut down without user interference).
Using SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX) works for several other kinds of exceptions (out of memory, for example), but not for stack overflow.

I'm looking for a solution that works only on my application, as I cannot disable this for all the other applications.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm simulating the stack overflow myself (among several other crashes). This isn't an actual defect in my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the "Application Error" dialog box be disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735170/can-the-application-error-dialog-box-be-disabled)

Comment: Thanks Joe, but the solutions presented in your link are the ones I referred to as not working (SetErrorMode) or irrelevant (disabling this dialog altogether)

Comment: Have you tried the possible solutions offered here?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315937

Comment: If Joe's links don't help, you might need to split the program into two processes, and have one debugging the other.

Comment: Joe - these solutions aren't relevant either since I cannot know which thread is about to throw the exception, so I cannot use _try / _except.
Harry - what do you mean by debugging one process by the other?